# PostgreSQL database not showing data on Django website

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views

I've converted my SQLite DB to a PostgreSQL DB.
I've made all the migrations and collectstatic, and in my python script on my windows PC, I can access the DB and execute commands.
My problem is that I don't see all that data on my website...It's like the server and Python talk to each other but not to the website.

Here are a couple of code snippets-

- **PC Python Script**

```
    def get_query(group_name , heb_sale_rent ,heb_street, heb_city , heb_rooms , heb_size , heb_floor , heb_porch , heb_storage , heb_mamad , heb_parking , heb_elevator , heb_phone , heb_price):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database='test', host='192.168.72.130', port='5432', user='user_sql', password='user_sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM to_excel")
        query = cur.fetchall()
```

if I run this command I can see results I have added to the DB-

[image]

All of the lines above I've added with an INSERT command like so-

```
elif query == []:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO to_excel (id,group_name,sale_rent ,street, city , rooms , size , floor , porch , storage , mamad , parking , elevator , phone , price , date) VALUES (%s,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s ,%s, %s)", ('1', group_name , heb_sale_rent , heb_street, heb_city , heb_rooms , heb_size , heb_floor , heb_porch , heb_storage , heb_mamad , heb_parking , heb_elevator , heb_phone , heb_price , USER_DATE))
    user_date_str = USER_DATE
    user_date = datetime.strptime(user_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

(so far so good)

- **On My Ubuntu Server**

```
    #in settings.py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'test',
            'USER': 'user_sql',
            'PASSWORD': 'user_sql',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

**This is my views.py-**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Groups
from datetime import datetime


def index(request):
  group_names = Groups.objects.all().values()
  group_count = Groups.objects.count()
  index_list = [i+1 for i in range(group_count)]
  combined_list = zip(group_names, index_list)
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  context = {
    'group_data': combined_list,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def add(request):
  template = loader.get_template('add.html')
  return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))


def addrecord(request):
  group = request.POST['group']
  heb_street = 'רחוב, ברובע'
  heb_sale_rent = 'מכירה, השכרה'
  heb_city = 'שכונת, בסמטאות'
  heb_rooms = 'חדרים'
  heb_size = 'מ״ר, מ"ר'
  heb_floor = 'קומה'
  heb_porch = 'מרפסת'
  heb_storage = 'מחסן'
  heb_mamad = 'ממד, ממ״ד'
  heb_parking = 'חניה, חנייה, חניית, חנית'
  heb_elevator = 'מעלית'
  heb_price = 'מחיר, מבקשים'
  heb_phone = '054, 052, 053'
  date = datetime.now().strftime('%d %b %Y')
  group = Groups(group_name=group, sale_rent=heb_sale_rent, street=heb_street, city=heb_city, rooms=heb_rooms, size=heb_size, floor=heb_floor, elevator=heb_elevator, porch=heb_porch, storage=heb_storage, mamad=heb_mamad, parking=heb_parking, price=heb_price, phone=heb_phone, user_date=date)
  group.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def delete(request, id):
  group = Groups.objects.get(id=id)
  group.delete()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def update(request, id):
  group = Groups.objects.get(id=id)
  template = loader.get_template('update.html')
  context = {
    'group': group,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def updaterecord(request, id):
  group_name = request.POST['group']
  sale_rent = request.POST['sale_rent']
  street = request.POST['street']
  city = request.POST['city']
  rooms = request.POST['rooms']
  size = request.POST['size']
  floor = request.POST['floor']
  porch = request.POST['porch']
  storage = request.POST['storage']
  mamad = request.POST['mamad']
  elevator = request.POST['elevator']
  parking = request.POST['parking']
  price= request.POST['price']
  phone= request.POST['phone']
  date = request.POST['user_date']
  group = Groups.objects.get(id=id)
  group.group_name = group_name
  group.sale_rent = sale_rent
  group.street = street
  group.city = city
  group.rooms = rooms
  group.size = size
  group.floor = floor
  group.porch = porch
  group.storage = storage
  group.mamad = mamad
  group.elevator = elevator
  group.parking = parking
  group.price = price
  group.phone = phone
  group.user_date = date
  group.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**This is my models.py-**

```
from django.db import models


class Groups(models.Model):
  group_name = models.TextField()
  sale_rent = models.TextField()
  street = models.TextField()
  city = models.TextField()
  rooms = models.TextField()
  size = models.TextField()
  floor = models.TextField()
  porch = models.TextField()
  storage = models.TextField()
  mamad = models.TextField()
  parking = models.TextField()
  elevator = models.TextField()
  phone = models.TextField()
  price = models.TextField()
  user_date = models.TextField()
```

[image]

- **But on the website- nada-**

[image]

Where is all the data that Python printed out in the query? What am I doing wrong?
help, please!

**P.S**- I don't know if it has any relevance, but when I run

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

and then do \dt, I don't see any tables.

- **Additional Debugging INformation:**

**When I run print(group_names) in views.py I get an empty query! why?**

Comment: Your `get_query` method doesn't return anything. Try adding `return query`

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the problem... I also run insert commands, the query is only for getting the data. I'll add a snippet of my insert command

Comment: How you are getting data to the frontend? Usually you call some endpoint and it RETURN data that you display on the website. Not returning any query you made could be possible issue.

You need to provide more data. Share your models and views (endpoint)

Comment: sure thing, Ill add my model and my views in the question's body

Comment: 1) This `sudo -u postgres psql` is going to connect to the `postgres` database as you did not specify a database with `-d <db_name>`. So it is not surprising there is no tables. 2) You will need to show the view you use to get the data to the page.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver oh cool I can my tables now on the DB, Ill post the code now :-)

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do the `sudo`. You can do from your user shell `psql -d test -U user_sql -h localhost p 5432`. Also do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste the text to the question.

Comment: Have no idea how the `Groups` model maps to the `to_excel` table?

Comment: I guess it's through the settings.py, let me check again if everything is configured correctly

Comment: the settings.py seem to be configured correctly, and python can talk to the remote DB and save information on it. I'll try to check the views.py on the server again

Comment: the query in views.py is returning an empty query! but why??

Comment: And also- in the admin page I can see the table name

Comment: What table name?  You have `"SELECT * FROM to_excel"` that outputs data. Then you have `Groups` model which would  by default point at a  table named `groups`. I don't see how those are related?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  I'm lost :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after almost becoming mentally insane I FOUND THE PROBLEM.
Looks like the website used a table in my DB called- to_excel_toexcel.
the "to_excel" is a table I've created in the DB, and "toexcel" is the name of my model!

I configured Python to write to the new table and everything works perfectly!
[image]